# How to display value of another cell in their original style?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Cell A1 has the text "**Bold** normal". If inside cell A2 I type `=A1`, "Bold normal" will be displayed without the bold styling. Is there any way to make A2 have the same content and format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is purely for data. Strings, integers, etc... You have to apply formatting afterwards. There's no `=copyformat(A1)` type function in Excel.

The easiest way to clone formatting is to use the [Format Painter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-format-painter-4bb415a9-d4e4-42b7-b579-170adc594e40?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: Format Painter won't duplicate mixed formatting like my example, but thanks for letting me know that it can't be done in Excel, and I have to copy the content myself whenever I make changes.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can use `Range.Value(11)` property to copy cell contents with formatting. 11 stands for **xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet** constant. The syntax is:

```
dest.Value(11) = src.Value(11)
```

*dest* and *src* represent destination and source ranges, respectively. They may be individual cells or rectangular areas of the same size.
If you want to call it from a sheet you must define a UDF function. It is not a typical use of such a function, but it works. There are (at least) two variants, how you can use it.
**Variant 1.**

```
Function CPF(src As Range, dest As Range) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    dest.Value(11) = src.Value(11)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

In the empty cell you put the function call.

```
=CPF(A1, A2)
```

Separator as you have defined locally: comma or semicolon. The cell contents (formatted text constant) from A1 is copied to A2. The function returns an empty string, but you can make it visible if you wish. Function is recalculated if any changes are made to the cell values (A1 or A2) or cells are edited. No recalculation when only format has been changed.
**Variant 2.**
You can call the UDF from the **Name Box**. In this case a function should return reference to the cell (cells) which become selected after completing the task. There are two possible versions of the code.
*Version A* (source selected, destination given as argument):

```
Function CNFx(dest As Range) As Range
    Dim src As Range
    Set src = Selection
    On Error Resume Next
    dest.Value(11) = src.Value(11)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set CNFx = dest
End Function
```

The cell to copy must be selected. Destination address is given as an argument. In the Name Box (on the sheet of the source cell) you enter e.g.:

```
CNFx(Sheet2!B5)
```

`=` is not necessary. Destination cell becomes selected after copying.
*Version B* (both source and destination given as arguments):

```
Function CNF(src As Range, dest As Range) As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    dest.Value(11) = src.Value(11)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set CNF = dest
End Function
```

In the **Name Box** you enter e.g.:

```
CNF(Sheet1!A2:A3, Sheet2!B5:B6)
```

Destination cells become selected after copying.
The difference between these two variants is that in the first one the function call remains in the sheet and is recalculated if necessary, whereas in the second one it is performed only once and is removed.
**Note:** Using **Format Painter** you can copy only whole-cell formatting, not the formatting of individual characters.

[image: Copy Formatted Text by UDF]